# How do I delete files marked for add from my local disk?

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v

I'm currently using Perforce with P4V (Rev. Perforce Visual Client/MACOSX105X86_64/2012.1/490402) in Unity 3.5.5,

When you revert files marked for add, it only removes it from the changelist. Sometimes files are auto generated or I created some files that I don't want to add anymore and I want to remove them from the changelist and delete the local copy of it.

This also occurs when shelving files marked for add. I'm currently manually reverting and deleting each file. Is there a way to easily delete the local copies?

Comment: Are you currently right-clicking the files you want to delete in the Workspace tab of P4V and selecting "Delete Local File" ?  That's the best way I know in P4V; you'd have to script something from the command line if you want to delete multiple files in one operation.

Comment: Actions > Delete Local File, seem to be greyed out for me and hidden for the context menu when I right click a changelist item.

If I can get that to work it would be exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: So it seems that "Delete Local File" only works in the workspace view and not on anything currently in a changelist.

Is there a way to "Revert" then "Delete Local File" for file inside a changelist?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it please.

Comment: My mistake, its confusing since Unity3d has stopped calling itself Unity3d for a very long time.

Answer (score 4):

We haven't implemented it in P4V yet, but if you are on at least a 2013.2 server, you can use 'p4 revert -w' to do this in one step. If you follow the advice of the custom tool route, the command is super simple since it's a one-step process. You can just have the application be p4.exe (or p4 binary if you're on Linux or Mac) and the arguments are 'revert -w %F'.

Comment: [P4V now supports deleting files directly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30049811/28411)

Comment: It does (and has for awhile) but it doesn't do it in the one step that revert -w does. It's just a convenience thing. :)

Answer (score 1):

There may not be an ability built into p4v, but you can call your own script from p4v, in which the script calls a revert and delete on the file.

Go to `Tools->Manage Custom Tools...`, and select `New->Tool`.

You'll get a dialog as seen below.

[image]
You would put your user script in the `Application`.  For the `Arguments`, you can click the `Select...` button to choose the different variables.  Here, `%F` refers to the file you right-clicked on (can be multiple).

I haven't actually written an entire script to test this, but I verified that you can at least right-click a file and this script is available (provided you check `Add to applicable context menus`).

Comment: Cool, Thanks for getting the ball rolling on this. So, now I'll have to make a script that deletes the local file and then sends command line to P4V to revert the changelist file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from the "Reconcile offline work" tool.

Right-click on the pending-add, "Delete local file":

[image: Screenshot in p4]

(p4v 2015 February 18 1007540)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little dangerous, as you'll need to ensure you don't have anything on your client that you want to keep that isn't also in the P4 repository.  Once you verify that you want to delete all non-p4-versioned files...

1. Right-click the containing directory or depot, and choose "reconcile offline work".
2. This opens a dialog box.  You'll see a section called "Local files not in depot", which are the files that were presumably auto-generated that you want to delete.
3. Select all the files in "Local files not in depot" (ctrl+A), right-click on them, and choose "Delete Local File".
4. Answer yes, you're sure you want to delete the file(s).

This should remove any files from your p4 client (under the directory you choose) that aren't under p4 version control.